# MSSQL InvalidCastException - Problem with Attribute of type text - Unable to cast to Micosoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParamater

Tags: mdriven

[image]

Installed latest MDriven version and made some other changes and now I MDriven is unable to save text attribute to MS SQL Server. See below for error message. Demo project has Class1.Attribute1 is Attribute1:Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the stuff to communicate with SQLServer was in System.Data - but Microsoft has abandoned that and everything plus new stuff is now in a nuget library called Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

The switch was forced due to AzureSQL connection string ability to set ActiveDirectoryIntegrated.

I also added a new wik post on this: https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Microsoft.data

Comment: Reference to System.Data.SqlClient removed and all good now , thanks.